# How to get only last row after inner join?

Tags: sql-server

I need to return unique `funeral_homes` who contains not completed leads and sort these by last lead timestamp.

This is my sql query:

```
select distinct h.funeral_home_name, h.funeral_home_guid, h.address1, h.city, h.state, p.discount_available, t.date_created
from tblFuneralHomes h inner join tblFuneralTransactions t on h.funeral_home_guid = t.funeral_home_guid 
inner join vwFuneralHomePricing p on h.funeral_home_guid = p.funeral_home_guid where completed=0 order by 'funeral_home_name' asc;
```

This is the result, but I need only unique homes with last added lead

[image]
What I should change here?

Comment: You should add sample data and the expected output, for all tables, to your question.

Comment: We can't see your screen, and we don't work at your company. What's a "last lead timestamp"? There are no tables or columns in your query that include any of those words. [Help us help you](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/).

Comment: @EricBrandt Sorry for bad question. One `funeral_home` includes many leads. I should return list of funeral_homes and sort these by last lead (`date_created`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here appears that you are joining into tables with 1 to many relationships with table `tblFuneralHomes`, yet you expect only one row per funeral home.

Instead of using `distinct`, I would suggest that instead you group by the required output funeral home columns, and then apply some kind of aggregate on the columns needed from the joined tables in order to return just a single computed value from all possible joined values.

For instance, below we find the first transaction date (`min`) associated with each funeral home:

```
select h.funeral_home_name, h.funeral_home_guid, h.address1, h.city, h.state,
       p.discount_available, min(t.date_created)
from tblFuneralHomes h 
inner join tblFuneralTransactions t on h.funeral_home_guid = t.funeral_home_guid 
inner join vwFuneralHomePricing p on h.funeral_home_guid = p.funeral_home_guid 
where completed=0 
group by h.funeral_home_name, h.funeral_home_guid, h.address1, h.city, h.state, 
         p.discount_available
order by h.funeral_home_name asc
```

Note that depending on the cardinality of the association between `tblFuneralHomes` and `vwFuneralHomePricing`, you may also need to remove `p.discount_available` from the grouping and also introduce it with an aggregate function, similar to what I've done with `t.date_created`